# Weird graphical issues with Gnome Shell in 12.10

Tags: gnome, 12.10

I finally got Gnome Shell working on Ubuntu 12.10, but there are some weird graphical issues. It seems as if the text is corrupted or something. Here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about:

[image]

It happens on a bunch of different applications, but not when I'm using Ubuntu. Does anyone know why or how to fix it?

My graphics card is an AMD Radeon HD 6540G2, and I'm using the open source drivers (fglrx doesn't work with 12.10 yet).

EDIT: I left it for an hour to take a shower. It locked, and when I came back it was much worse:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall Gnome shell?